# RRULE for first Advent

Tags: icalendar, rrule

I am currently trying to setup my own holiday iCalendar to which I can subscribe on, since I don't want to depend on 3rd party services.

I am currently trying to make the the `VEVENT`s for Christmas. The 2nd, 3rd and 4th advent, as well as the Christmas holidays are straight forward, however I have big issues to model the 1st advent.

Specifically, the problem is that the first advent can be in November and December (27th November to 3rd Devember)

**How can I make a recurring event (or, more specifically, the `RRULE`) to cover all cases for the 1st advent?**

## What I've tried

---

My first idea was this:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11,12;BYMONTHDAY=27,28,29,30,1,2,3;BYDAY=SU
```

The idea was to just pick the one Sunday in between 27th November and 3rd December. This does of course not work because `BYMONTH` expands the search to all days in November and December, and `BYMONTHDAY` limits the search to those days in both months. I.e. November 1st, November 2nd, ... December 27th, December 28th, ..., which is of course not what I want.

---

Next, I tried to use `BYYEARDAY=331,332,333,334,335,336,337` instead of `BYMONTHDAY` and `BYMONTH`, but unfortunately my webdav server (Nextcloud, which uses Sabre as far as I know. I got an error message "Invalid BYYEARDAY rule") does not support this.

---

My next idea was to use multiple `RRULE`s -- at least I did not see any passage in the RFC stating that only one `RRULE` is allowed at most. So I ended up with:

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYMONTHDAY=27,28,29,30;BYMONTH=11
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3;BYMONTH=12
```

Didn't work as well. My last resort was to create two separate `VEVENT`s, one with the first `RRULE` above and one with the second `RRULE` above, but otherwise identical. This worked, but it left me confused.

Is there no better solution? How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unfortunately my webdav server (Nextcloud, which uses Sabre as far as I know. I got an error message "Invalid BYYEARDAY rule") does not support this.

Well I think you should raise a bug report, because as far I can tell your solutions are correct and RFC-compliant.

I tried your solutions 2 and 3 with different libs (my own lib `php-rrule`, and `rrule.js`) and both options seems to work just fine.

`FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=SU;BYYEARDAY=331,332,333,334,335,336,337`

or combining 2

`FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYMONTHDAY=27,28,29,30;BYMONTH=11`
`FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3;BYMONTH=12`

will both produce:

```
2018-12-02
2019-12-01
2020-11-29
2021-11-28
2022-11-27
2023-12-03
2024-12-01
2025-11-30
2026-11-29
2027-11-28
```

which according to Google and Wikipedia are the correct dates for the 1st Advent Sunday in the next 10 years.

#### Side note

> at least I did not see any passage in the RFC stating that only one RRULE is allowed at most.

While not strictly forbidden, in RFC 5545 it's literally written *everytime* `RRULE` is mentioned:

```
;
; The following is OPTIONAL,
; but SHOULD NOT occur more than once.
;
rrule
```

[Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-166) even states in the "New restrictions":

```
2.  The "RRULE" property SHOULD NOT occur more than once in a
   component.
```

That being said, multiple RRULE is a great feature, I don't know why they restricted it.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I will file a bug report in Nextcloud since I am not sure if the problem comes from SabreDAV or some JS library (the error I mentioned was printed in the JS console). I did not see the part about the RRULE being unique, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the first Advent is always the fifth last Sunday in a year. So the following rule should do the trick:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-5SU
```

See the next 10 results: http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20181202&rrule=FREQ%3DYEARLY%3BBYDAY%3D-5SU&max_instances=10

Or to put it another way:

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=SU;BYSETPOS=-5
```